# Fog lights on motorcycle with 2 power sources

Tags: automotive

I am trying to add fog lights to my 2023 fltrx. I am having trouble figuring out the wiring and praying someone here can help. I would like a setup where:

1. I turn on the high beams and the fog lights turn on
2. I press the rear brake and the fog lights strobe

I have a flasher/strobe module which switches patterns to each fog lamp separately. I like this. My fog lamps have two separate sets Of wires. I will combine them together. I’m attaching a picture here to help explain what I am thinking.

[image]

Or what about this

[image]

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: Question is how do I send power to the fog lamps using either the flasher module when brakes are applied OR constant power when headlights/brights are on?

Comment: Sounds like not exactly legal to add extra blinking lights to your bike. Be sure the lights and lamps themselves are legal and they operate legally on your bike. Depends on country of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this:

[image]

I used the relays to supply the fog lights so they are kept separate as the flasher unit has separate outputs.

I would assume that all you need is a supply from the brake lights so not sure what you meant with the box - but I kept your structure.

You need to add supply fuses as appropriate - battery supply to the relays etc.

Comment: Thanks  for this. Would this cause a problem if the brakes are applied while the headlights are supplying power (2 simultaneous sources are ON)? If not then would the fog lamps be on constant or strobe in this situation?

Comment: Should be clear that the brake light supply just triggers the flasher unit, while the headlight supply operates the relays so no backfeed possible for either to the other.  But you could add blocking diodes between the flasher + to each light and the point where the headlight relay feed joins.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes total sense.  One more question - with your design, do I still need two relays? What would be the benefit of keeping two vs just one?

Comment: Do 1 relay with blocking diodes then, up to you.

Comment: Quick question: is there a way to put the relay BEFORE the flasher? Someone told me that the crazy power on/off from the strobe will burn the relay.

Answer (score 1):

Two 12 V DC, automotive SPDT relays should serve the purpose.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks like this will work too. I have the same question as above: might this design burn the relay due to too much switching by the flasher module? How can I prevent this?

Comment: You are most welcome!  There is no question of the relay contacts burning as it's the flasher that switches and not the relays.